# MS Edge URLs for buttons for Downloads, Collections, Favorites

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge

I've recently enabled an Allow List ( https://example.com ) and Block List ( * ) for my organization's MS Edge.  This works great for the intended purpose, locking it down to a small set of websites.  However, if I click the "Downloads" button in Edge, I see "downloads is blocked.  Your organization doesn't allow you to view this site".  Similar results come from clicking Collections button or Favorites button.

The file still downloads as needed, it will just worry my users if they don't know if the download completed or not.  Being able to click into it and open it from the Downloads button is also very useful.

I probably need to add some specific local paths to the Allow List, but am not certain where I can find those.  Any ideas?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#urlblocklist

Comment: The local URLs will all begin with edge://. Downloads is edge://downloads/all, Favorites is edge://favorites/, Settings is edge://settings.

Comment: Just like the chrome:// links , thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge local URLs all begin with the "edge://" protocol. "chrome://" also works but redirects to "edge://".

- Downloads is edge://downloads/all
- Favorites is edge://favorites/
- Settings is edge://settings

I would guess that your allow list would have to allow either all "edge://" protocol links, or specifically allow the areas you want your staff to be allowed to access.